# how to join two tables together with condition and sum them up?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I had sql command that successfully display income report for product that contain the sum of vat and non-vat and Gross total in specific year. Now that I want a report that show income year by year. I've tried to modified the existing sql command but when executed it, the result was incorrect. So would you kindly help me check this? With my limited skill of sql, I was stuck here for months.

My tables are below

**tbl_bill_total**

```
bill_id | bill_total | cust_id | shown date
  1     |   500      |   12    |  6/6/12
  2     |   500      |   14    |  8/8/12
  3     |   1000     |   13    |  10/11/12
  4     |   1000     |   12    |  12/10/13
  5     |   1200     |   13    |  1/11/13
  6     |   500      |   12    |  3/11/13
```

**tbl_vat_bill_total**

```
vat_id  |  vat_total |  if_paid| showndate | cust_id 
  1     |    100     |   false |  1/6/12   |  10
  2     |    200     |   true  |  2/6/12   |  11
  3     |    100     |   true  |  7/8/12   |  12
  1     |    400     |   false |  13/10/13 |  14
  2     |    500     |   true  |  14/11/13 |  12
  3     |    100     |   false |  15/11/13 |  11
  4     |    200     |   true  |  20/11/13 |  12
```

The expected result should be like this

```
bill_total  |  vat_total | Sum_of_all | month  | year
  500       |   200      |   700      |   6    |  2012
  1000      |   100      |   1100     |   8    |  2012
  1000      |   0        |   1000     |  11    |  2012       
  1000      |    0       |   1000     |  10    |  2013
  1700      |    700     |   2400     |  11    |  2013
```

Here is my sql command that didn't work…

```
select 
    sum(tbt.bill_total) as bill_total_
    ,iif(sum_vat_total is null, 0, sum_vat_total) as vat_total_
    ,iif(sum_vat_total is null, 0, sum_vat_total) + sum(bill_total) as sum_of_all
    ,month(showndate) as month
    ,year(showndate) as yearall
from tbl_bill tbt
left join (
    select 
        sum(vat_total) as sum_vat_total
        ,month(showndate) as month
        ,year(showndate) as yearall
    from tbl_vat
    where if_paid = true

    group by 
        month(showndate)
        ,year(showndate)
    ) tvt
        on tvt.month = month(tbt.showndate) 

group by 
    month(showndate)
    ,sum_vat_total
    ,year(showndate)
```

Comment: A fiddle would be helpful: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: What do you get instead as a result? @Ean: SqlFiddle does not have a MS Access profile. But nevertheless it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a solution for your problem. This SQL should work in MS Access but I tested it with SQL Server because there was no Access available :(. `If_Paid` is a `varchar` in my version, so you should remove the quotes.

```
select 
sum(bill_total) as bill_total_, 
sum(vat_total) as vat_total_,
sum(bill_total) + sum(vat_total) as sum_of_all,
month, yearall
from 
  (select 
  bill_total, 0 as vat_total, month(showndate) as month, year(showndate) as yearall
  from tbl_bill_total
  union all
  select 
  0 as bill_total, vat_total, month(showndate) as month, year(showndate) as yearall
  from tbl_vat_bill_total where if_paid='true') data
group by month, yearall
```

In the inner select I collect all `bill_total` and all `vat_total` values. Here is no grouping. That happens in the outer select by `month` and `yearall`.

With this I got your wished result, except 2012/08 I think you got a typo here bill_total should be here 500.

This is my SQL to build up the test data:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_bill_total
    (bill_id int, bill_total int, cust_id int, showndate datetime)
;

INSERT INTO tbl_bill_total
    (bill_id, bill_total, cust_id, showndate)
VALUES
    (1, 500, 12, '2012-06-06 02:00:00'),
    (2, 500, 14, '2012-08-08 02:00:00'),
    (3, 1000, 13, '2012-10-11 02:00:00'),
    (4, 1000, 12, '2013-12-10 01:00:00'),
    (5, 1200, 13, '2013-01-11 01:00:00'),
    (6, 500, 12, '2013-03-11 01:00:00')
;



CREATE TABLE tbl_vat_bill_total
    (vat_id int, vat_total int, if_paid varchar(5), showndate datetime, cust_id int)
;

INSERT INTO tbl_vat_bill_total
    (vat_id, vat_total, if_paid, showndate, cust_id)
VALUES
    (1, 100, 'false', '2012-01-06 01:00:00', 10),
    (2, 200, 'true', '2012-02-06 01:00:00', 11),
    (3, 100, 'true', '2012-07-08 02:00:00', 12),
    (1, 400, 'false', '2013-13-10 01:00:00', 14),
    (2, 500, 'true', '2013-14-11 01:00:00', 12),
    (3, 100, 'false', '2013-15-11 01:00:00', 11),
    (4, 200, 'true', '2013-20-11 02:00:00', 12)
;
```

Comment: thank you for you effort, however after execute in access there's the error said "Circular reference caused by alias "bill_total" in query definition's SELECT list. and when I changed them all to other name, it said "Data type mismatch in criteria expression". so confused..

Comment: Ok. Then you have to modify the aliases.  E.g. as bill_total_

Comment: and when I changed them all to other name, it said "Data type mismatch in criteria expression". so confused..

Comment: Did you changed if_paid="true" to if_paid=true? You know I had a datatype typo in the inserts. Or The datatypes of my union selects do not fit. Maybe in your tables the datatypes are different from what I used. Nevertheless if you got this error the statement seems to by syntactically correct and there is like it displayed a data (type) error. A cast could correct this. But I don't know your exact datatypes.

Comment: After I removed "" in true, it works. Don't know how to say… really really thank you to you.. I was stuck here for few months and think it's hopeless.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Next time you should provide something in sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

please try below method

```
select b.bill_total, v.vat_total, b.bill_total + v.vat_total as 'sum_of_all', month(v.showndate) as 'month', year(v.showndate) as 'Year'
from tbl_vat_bill_total v join tbl_bill_total b
on b.cust_id = v.cust_id
where v.if_paid=true
```

Comment: thank you for you effort, but it said "Syntax error in FROM cause".